# How can I add an addon to my webdriver browser

Tags: java, selenium

Whenever I execute my script created in selenium webdriver (java), the webdriver browser does not show the addons that I had installed in my actual browser. 
I want that the add ons should also be displayed in webdriver browser.
How can I add an addon to my webdriver browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you can add Firebug add-on in the Firefox profile used for the Selenium tests:

```
File file = new File("firebug-1.8.1.xpi");
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1"); // Avoid startup screen
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Comment: Getting an error after using above code:-
 Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
null                                                                                         
Any idea how to resolve this error

Comment: @user2695440 Most likely reason is that the extension file cannot be located. Have you provided the correct path to the .xpi file?

Comment: @JaceKm Yes i gave  the location of .xpi file.